# DocuSign Connect - Error - The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable

Tags: django, heroku, docusignapi, webhooks, docusignconnect

DocuSign Connect Push is showing the following error:

```
Error - The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
```

When I tried the same with postman the API is working. Any help will be appreciated. The project is hosted in Heroku.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm happy that I was able to help you! Please accept (check) the best answer to each of your questions. THANK YOU, Larry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using connect webhooks? The error means that your server responded with a 503 error to DocuSign.

Check your server logs.

Also check out the [postman replay technique](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/replaying-webhook-messages-postman).

### Added

To test your webhook listener (your server), you need to use the **exact** same request (as a POST) as the request (notification) from DocuSign.

Anything else is not a real test. Use the [postman replay technique](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/replaying-webhook-messages-postman) to capture a notification and then replay it to your server.

Comment: Yes its showing 503. But in postman, I am not getting this error. sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=POST path="/push/" host=myport-cornerstone.herokuapp.com request_id=73a1f799-071f-42a5-866b-751d4e022c61 fwd="64.207.219.9" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=148ms status=503 bytes=3653 protocol=https

Comment: Best is to send an exact duplicate of what DocuSign is sending. Use the postman replay technique. Since your postman request to your server is not giving the same response, you're not making the same request...

Comment: Yes done postman replay technique and its working fine. I have done the same using the request body given in the developer admin log. Now  I think the issue is with SSL certificate. The heroku free plan gives HTTPS but no SSL certificate. Thanks again.